# Why use bindActionCreator instead of passing an object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
 return { todos: state.todos }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return { actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch) }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoApp)
```

why would i use mapDispatchToProps and bindActionCreators as second prop if

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getSthAction })(TodoApp)
```

this way it works as well? is there any difference?

Answer (score 1):

The only difference in those examples is that your `mapDispatch` function will result in `this.props.actions.someAction()`, rather than `this.props.someAction()`, because you're explicitly returning the result of `bindActionCreators` as a field called `actions`.

I personally recommend *always* using the "object shorthand" version - to me, there's *never* a good reason to actually write a separate `mapDispatch` function.