# React component doesn't connect to the store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have been using [this](https://gist.github.com/robertgonzales/e54699212da497740845712f3648d98c) to create the following.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import {Alert, No} from './pure/Icons/Icons';
import Button from './pure/Button/Button';
import Modal from './pure/Modal/Modal';

import {setWarning} from '../actions/app/appActions';

const WarningModal = ({withCleanup, message, isWarning}) => {
    const [
        title,
        text,
        leave,
        cancel
    ] = message.split('|');

    console.log(isWarning)

    const handleOnClick = () => {
        setWarning(false);
        withCleanup(true);
    }

    return(
        <Modal>
            <header>{title}</header>
            <p>{text}</p>
            <Alert />
            <div className="modal__buttons-wrapper modal__buttons-wrapper--center">
                <button 
                    onClick={() => withCleanup(false)} 
                    className="button modal__close-button button--icon button--icon-only button--text-link"
                >
                    <No />
                </button>
                <Button id="leave-warning-button" className="button--transparent-bg" onClick={() => handleOnClick()}>{leave}</Button>
                <Button id="cancel-warning-button" onClick={() => withCleanup(false)}>{cancel}</Button>
            </div>
        </Modal>
    );
}

WarningModal.propTypes = {
    withCleanup: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    message: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    isWarning: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isWarning: state.app.isWarning
    }
};

connect(mapStateToProps, {
    setWarning
})(WarningModal);

export default (message, callback) => {
    const modal = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(modal);

    const withCleanup = (answer) => {
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(modal);
        document.body.removeChild(modal);
        callback(answer);
    };

    ReactDOM.render(
        <WarningModal 
            message={message} 
            withCleanup={withCleanup} 
        />,
        modal
    );
};
```

I need to dispatch an action to update a state property ('isWarning') which controls the visibility of 'WarningModal', however this doesn't seem to connect my component to the store:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, {
    setWarning
})(WarningModal);

ConfigureStore.js

...
    return createStore(
        combineReducers(reducers),
        composeEnhancers(
            applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
        )
    );
...
```

Comment: Are you using combineReducers? Can you share your reducer/rootReducer structure?

Comment: please check this , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251827/why-use-bindactioncreator-instead-of-passing-an-object

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky yes I am

Comment: I'm trying to understand if your `mapStateToProps` configured correctly. The question about the `combineReducers` was to get information regarding the keys/namespaces of your state/store. Can you `console.log(state)` inside `mapStateToProps ` and share the output please?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky it's undefined, the relative action and reducers are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `connect()` returns a wrapped React component constructor. This code is not using the return value of `connect` at all, so it's thrown away.

The smallest change that should fix this would be to save the return value from `connect` in a new variable, and use that in place of `WarningModal` in the exported component constructor's render function:

```
const WarningModalContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, {
    setWarning
})(WarningModal);
```

...

```
ReactDOM.render(
        <WarningModalContainer 
            message={message} 
            withCleanup={withCleanup} 
        />,
        modal
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  setWarning
})(WarningModal);
```

This way you cen import redux connected component for rendering (in separate file) - in your version render takes original (not connected) component for mount,

It can be done in one file but it isn't recommended.